# How to remove ripple effect from React Navigation Drawer Item?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

[image]

When I press drawer Item, I see 2 colors

1. Item button background color (in the center with ripple effect)
2. Active background color of the item.

On pressing the item, the ripple effect appears and then screen is loaded. I used InteractionManager but still the drawer stays open until the ripple effect completes.

How can I remove this ripple effect ? So, on pressing the item, the drawer should closed instantly.